# jQuery: Click an element and add a class to a div, click away and it removes class

Tags: jquery

I've researching this problem and I can find a solution for adding/removing a class to the div i'm clicking, but not a separate div altogether e.g.

Click the input with the class .search-bar....  and it adds a class to a div called .search-wrap...  click anywhere else on page/off element it removes the class added to .search-wrap.

I've tried this:

```
$("div.search-bar").click(function(){
    $("div.search-wrap").addClass("white");
});
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: You say click the input and you use `$("div.search-bar")`... Can ou show your html?

Comment: Please post the HTML markup also..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('html').click(function() {
     $("div.search-wrap").removeClass("white");
});

$("div.search-bar").click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     $("div.search-wrap").addClass("white");
});
```

If you click on `div.search-bar`, `addClass` is called, but the event does not bubble up to `body`.
Any other click on the page will call `html`'s click handler, and remove the class.

Comment: Given that 'body' includes the div '.search-wrap', you might want to add a ".not('.search-wrap')" to your body click function, as per the question.

Comment: This seems to work very well for me, thank you very much for this :)

Comment: I would improve this answer (which is not wrong but...) cause after **every click** that will bubble down to the `html` element you're than searching for a `class` element and removing a class. Is that the best way to do it? **NO**

Answer (score 2):

You need change style only in focus state, and revert default state after finish editing

You dont need use click event  -  it is not appropriate way.

I think you should use **[focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)** and  **[blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)**

Ofcause you can add event on docuemnt or body, but this event will be fires at every time when you click at link, button and so on

Answer (score 2):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hemoza/1/edit)**

```
$(".search-bar").on('focus blur', function( e ){
    $(".search-wrap").toggleClass("white");
});
```

***[jsBin demo - Using DIV](http://jsbin.com/gagipi/1/edit)***

```
$(".search-bar").on('click', function( e ){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".search-wrap").addClass("white");
});
$(document).on('click', function( e ){
    if(e.target.className!="search-bar")
    $(".search-wrap").removeClass("white");
});
```

Comment: this is the better option, relying on the `$("html")` isnot stable as elements to be clicked are WITHIN the html tag, im speaking from `div` standpoint anyway, but you've ruined a good answer by removing that part ?

Answer (score 0):

And using the focusin() focusout()

When your input has it add the class, and when he lose it, remove the class ... what do you think about ?

```
$("div.search-bar").focusin(function(){
    $("div.search-wrap").addClass("white");
});
```

the rest :

```
$("div.search-bar").focusout(function() {
     $("div.search-wrap").removeClass("white");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> One Way

```
$(".search-bar").on("click", function(e) { $(".search-wrap").addClass("white"); });
$(".search-wrap").siblings().on("click", function() { $(".search-wrap").removeClass("white"); });
$(".search-wrap").siblings().parents().on("click", function() { $(".search-wrap").removeClass("white"); });
```

> Another Way

```
$(".search-bar").on("click", function(e) { $(".search-wrap").addClass("white"); });
$("body, body *").not(".search-wrap, .search-wrap *").on("click", function() { $(".search-wrap").removeClass("white"); });
```

Both with their own pros and cons, namely in speed of response on slower systems and possible HTML layout

and if you can use the input in the div, the best way would be:

```
$(".search-bar input").on("focus", function(e) { $(".search-wrap").addClass("white"); })
.on("blur", function(e) { $(".search-wrap").removeClass("white"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".search-bar").click(function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("div.search-wrap").addClass("white");
});

$(document).on("click", function () {

    $("div.search-wrap").removeClass("white");
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/jWJuu/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.search-bar').click(function() {
    $('div.search-wrap').addClass('white');
});
$('*:not(.search-bar)').click(function() {
    $('div.search-wrap).removeClass('white');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `.toggleClass` and `.blur`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-bar').blur(function(){
        $('.search-wrap').toggleClass('blue','red');
    });
});
```

I did a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/HqcG2/

toggleClass: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

blur: http://api.jquery.com/blur/